# Cannot deploy jar file with ejb to glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jboss7.x

I've tryed to deploy resulting jar file from 
[First example of ejb from Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1, 6th Edition by Andrew Lee Rubinger, Bill Burke](https://github.com/jbossejb3/oreilly-ejb-6thedition-book-examples/tree/master/ch04-firstejb)

to glassfish 3.1.1 and got the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method 'public abstract int org.jboss.ejb3.examples.ch04.firstejb.CalculatorCommonBusiness.add(int[])' must throw at least one exception of type java.rmi.RemoteException or one of its super-classes
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl.(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:232)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl.(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:65)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl$2.run(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:169)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl$2.run(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:167)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl.get(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:166)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl$ClassDataImpl.(PresentationManagerImpl.java:153)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl$1.lookup(PresentationManagerImpl.java:103)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl$1.lookup(PresentationManagerImpl.java:100)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.misc.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:114)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl.getClassData(PresentationManagerImpl.java:131)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.setTarget(ReflectiveTie.java:101)
>       at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.POAProtocolMgr.validateTargetObjectInterfaces(POAProtocolMgr.java:315)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1248)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:202)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
>       ... 55 more
>   Caused by: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLTypeException: Method 'public abstract int org.jboss.ejb3.examples.ch04.firstejb.CalculatorCommonBusiness.add(int[])' must throw at least one exception of type java.rmi.RemoteException or one of its super-classes
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLTypesUtil.validateExceptions(IDLTypesUtil.java:476)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLTypesUtil.validateRemoteInterface(IDLTypesUtil.java:100)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl.(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:226)
>       ... 71 more
>   |#]

But CommonBusiness is just an interface why it must throw any exceptions?!

Resulting jar contains only annotated beans and no ejb-jar.xml or some glassfish specific xml files (but as I understand javaee6 don't require any ejb-jar.xml nor server specific files...)

This jar was successfully deployed to JBoss AS7 so I don't know where to dig...

Comment: Please see:
https://github.com/jbossejb3/oreilly-ejb-6thedition-book-examples/tree/master/ch04-firstejb/src/main/java/org/jboss/ejb3/examples/ch04/firstejb

Answer (score 0):

I cannot navigate from pages to pages for a single source code.

But you must throw a RemoteException for that method

Comment: "I cannot navigate from pages to pages for a single source code." - ??

"But you must throw a RemoteException for that method" - why?

Answer (score 0):

I also trigger the problem using arquillian-glassfish-managed-3.1 and has sent into glassfish ejb leader.

However, I need to confirm the issue using other ways to judge whether being caused by glassfish or arquillian.

Comment: Now, I have filed a bug(https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1346) in arquillian jira and waiting for team's evaluation.